# gsed add _single_ newline at end of file

Tags: sed, newline, gnu

I'm attempting to create a *single* newline at the end of a file.
My command is this:

`gsed -i '$a\\r' outfiles/*.txt`

Somehow this creates **two** newlines, and I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my first thought I would on the last line substitute end of line with a newline.

```
sed '$s/$/\n/'
```

But my second thought is just nice:

```
sed '$G'
```

Grabbing from a hold space appends a newline to pattern space and then appends the hold space to pattern space. Because hold space is empty, it effectively adds just only the newline.

Comment: hold space is empty because no substitutions have been defined?

Comment: Hold space is empty because nothing was appended to hold space. You can use `h` or `H` to copy/append pattern space to hold space.

Answer (score 1):

Keep it clear and simple, just use gawk:

```
gawk -i inplace 'ENDFILE{print ""}' outfiles/*.txt
```